# NumPy: Find first n columns according to mask

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have an array `arr` in shape `(m, n)` and a boolean array `mask` in the same shape as `arr`. I would like to obtain the first `N` columns from `arr` that are `True` in `mask` as well.

An example:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
                [6,7,8,9,10],
                [11,12,13,14,15]])

mask = np.array([[False, True, True, True, True],
                [True, False, False, True, False],
                [True, True, False, False, False]]) 

N = 2
```

Given the above, I would like to write a (vectorized) function that outputs the following:

```
output = maskify_n_columns(arr, mask, N)
output = np.array(([2,3],[6,9],[11,12]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use broadcasting, [`numpy.cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and [`numpy.argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

```
def maskify_n_columns(arr, mask, N):
    m = (mask.cumsum(axis=1)[..., None] == np.arange(1,N+1)).argmax(axis=1)
    r = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None], m]
    return r

maskify_n_columns(arr, mask, 2)
```

Output:

```
[[ 2  3]
 [ 6  9]
 [11 12]]
```

Comment: let `a = (mask.cumsum(axis=1)[..., None]`, `b=np.arange(1,N+1)`. The `a==b` operation is the hot spot of the code due to the broadcasting in the third dimension. Is there a way to avoid this heavy usage of memory?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar issue and I wasn't satisfied with the performance of the currently accepted answer, so I managed to come up with a slightly faster version:

```py
def maskify_n_columns_ruro(arr, mask, N):
    order = (~mask).argsort(axis=-1, kind="stable")
    result = np.take_along_axis(arr, order[:, :N], axis=-1)
    return result
```

The trick is that you can just argsort the inverse of the mask, so that all the `True` values are at the beginning (`kind="stable"` ensures, that the relative order among `True` elements is not changed). After that, you can just take the first `N` elements in each row.

Keep in mind, that these solutions rely on there being at least `N` masked elements in each row.

Here are some timing results compared to [@imahdi's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735844/4317303):

```
# n, m, N = 10000, 16, 2
maskify_n_columns_imahdi: average of 235.46349519898132it/s over 1000 iterations
maskify_n_columns_ruro  : average of 317.19737852618005it/s over 1000 iterations

# n, m, N = 1000, 512, 2
maskify_n_columns_imahdi: average of 86.17337628403166it/s over 1000 iterations
maskify_n_columns_ruro  : average of 400.4593672929356it/s over 1000 iterations

# n, m, N = 100, 512, 256
maskify_n_columns_imahdi: average of 36.61469817111809it/s over 1000 iterations
maskify_n_columns_ruro  : average of 2978.410389545824it/s over 1000 iterations
```

As you can see, my solution performs slightly faster for small values of `m` and `N` and is **significantly** faster for large values of `m` and `N`. Here is the full code I used for timing:

```py
import timeit
import numpy as np


def maskify_n_columns_imahdi(arr, mask, N):
    m = (mask.cumsum(axis=1)[..., None] == np.arange(1,N+1)).argmax(axis=1)
    r = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None], m]
    return r


def maskify_n_columns_ruro(arr, mask, N):
    order = (~mask).argsort(axis=-1, kind="stable")
    result = np.take_along_axis(arr, order[:, :N], axis=-1)
    return result


# === Timing code ===

n, m, N = 100, 512, 256

number = 1000
repeat = 5
seed = 42


def generate_data():
    # Generate some random data
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    arr = rng.random(size=(n, m))

    # Generate a random mask
    assert m >= N
    order = rng.permuted(
        np.repeat(
            np.arange(m)[None],
            repeats=n,
            axis=0,
        ),
        axis=-1,
    )
    # (make sure that at least N elements are True per row)
    num_true = rng.integers(low=N, high=m+1, size=(n, 1))
    mask = order < num_true

    return arr, mask


def run_timeit(functions):
    arr, mask = generate_data()
    for function in functions:
        timer = timeit.Timer(lambda: function(arr, mask, N))
        # number, _ = timer.autorange()

        timings = timer.repeat(
            repeat=repeat,
            number=number,
        )
        avg_speed = np.mean([
            number / time
            for time in timings
        ])
        print(f"{function.__name__:<24}: average of {avg_speed}it/s over {number} iterations")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_timeit([
        maskify_n_columns_imahdi,
        maskify_n_columns_ruro,
    ])
```